# Validation for findOneAndUpdate doesn't have access to "this" values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got an Express endpoint that does the following:

```
router.put('/:appointmentId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let appointment = await Appointment.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.appointmentId },
      {
        member_id: req.body.appointment.memberId,
        client_id: req.body.appointment.clientId,
        address_id: req.body.appointment.addressId,
        unit_id: req.body.appointment.unitId,
        dateAndTime: req.body.appointment.dateAndTime
      },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        context: 'query'
      }
    );

    res.send(appointment);

  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

Appointment is a Mongoose model. This model has one of the following path validations:

```
AppointmentSchema.path("unit_id").validate(async function (unit_id) {

  let unit = await Unit.findById(unit_id);

  if ((unit === null) || !unit.address_id.equals(this.address_id)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}, "unit_id is not valid");
```

The Appointment schema looks like this:

```
var AppointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    member_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Member',
      required: true
    },
    client_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Client',
      required: true
    },
    address_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Address',
      required: true
    },
    unit_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Unit',
      required: true
    },
    dateAndTime: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  }
);
```

When I hit the Express endpoint, `this.address_id` is undefined and my validations don't work properly. It's my understanding that if I set `runValidators` to `true` and `context` to `'query'` that I'd have this access.

What am I doing wrong?

As a side-note, I also notice that Express is returning a `200` status when validation fails. This is curious.

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably not `this` but rather the instance does not have `address_id`. What is the schema, and/or any other validators for that path.

Comment: You're correct, `this` is defined, but `address_id` isn't available at `this.address_id`. I've just added the schema to the original question.

Comment: Seems one validator is fired before the other. You should be able to wrap with `this.hasOwnProperty('address_id')` to confirm it's actually there before you attempt to do anything. Where not, then the `required` validator on the `address_id` should "kick in" and return the error for that.

Comment: Personally, I think it's overkill. And what you likely should be doing instead is making sure the code can only "find or create" a valid "Unit" before you ever get to passing in these details. Putting an async constraint that goes and checks for existence in the database is just going to slow things down. You need to think "more relaxed" since this is NOT database enforced referential integrity, but a "client" action.

Comment: Can you give an example of using `this.hasOwnProperty('address_id')` in this case? There are three other validations that are similar, but I'm not sure I know what ordering they should be in. Should I share those above? Also, I'm curious about the "more relaxed" approach you're talking about. Should I just forget about referential integrity and just rely on the "client" or "user interface" to only allow valid appointments?

Comment: @NeilLunn - I did notice that ‘this’ is defined and that the ‘address_id’ is inside an ‘_update’ object. Could I just check for ‘address_id’ directly on ‘this’, if it’s not there then check if it’s on ‘Query._update’?